# PHP - Capture regex match as well as the non-matched remainder

Tags: php, regex

For a string like `asdftheremainderhere`, what is a simple way to split the string to `asdf` and `theremainderhere` using a regex to match `asdf`?

I tried using:

```
preg_match('/asdf|ghik/', 'asdftheremainderhere', $matches);`
```

But only `asdf` is the only element of `$matches`.

Comment: You need `preg_split` with a capture group around the `asdf`.

Comment: How can I capture the capture group? `$matches = preg_split('/(asdf)|(ghik)/', $string);`

Comment: You can just use `'(asdf|ghik)'`.

Comment: Clearly `preg_split` is the way to go, but with the option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` (see the php manual) and the pattern: `/(asdf|ghik)/`. Then, if you want to easily find only the delimiters, it's simple, it is all odd items (even items for other parts). The solution you accepted will fail if there's anything before "asdf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_split with `\K` which save delimiter

```
print_r(preg_split('/(asdf|ghik)\K/', 'asdftheremainderhere'));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdf
    [1] => theremainderhere
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `$matches` array `$matches[0]` will be the full pattern match, `$matches[1]` will be the first capture group `(asdf|ghik)` and `$matches[2]` will be the second capture group `(.*)` which is any character 0 or more times:

```
preg_match('/(asdf|ghik)(.*)/', 'asdftheremainderhere', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdftheremainderhere
    [1] => asdf
    [2] => theremainderhere
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture groups to so something like this, no?

```
preg_match('/(asdf)(.*)/', 'asdftheremainderhere', $matches);
```

and add the multiline flag if you expect newlines and want them in the remainder.